# How to use .less file in TYPO3 10x

Tags: typo3, less, typo3-10.x

I had to use some less files for my new website. In the Old website, I have used the dyncss, dyncss_less extensions for compiling the less files. Which is no more supported in new Typo3 versions(I want to implement the less files in TYPO3 10).

The only available extension for less compiler is: ws_less.
Tried to use this.. but after installing this one my website keeps loading and couldn't see if it is worked or not.

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you install `ws_less` correctly - as described here: https://docs.typo3.org/p/svewap/ws_less/1.5/en-us/Usage/Index.html

Comment: Yes. there is a loader on my pages. And it keeps loading and hiding the content. I can see the content when we hide the loader.